# Optimizing OneToMany FetchType.Edge in batch retrieval and Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a user requirement that requires me to list a set of data in a data tree table.

The set of data includes a one to many field.

Example: A product has a name , type and many colors.

So they colors are stored in another table (one to many relationship)

the user wants the datatable to list out the products and include the color as one of a field

Example: RED, GREEN, BLUE , Yellow (separated by color)

This is a very cost operation as it involve joining, therefore if there is 1000 products, it will take a long time to load.

OOT question.

For Criteria, I use list function. And I set ResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY) and setMaxResult(5000).

From my understanding, this will retrieve 5000 records do a result transformation on it

but that means I will have less than 5000 records listed at the end.

How do I ensure a min. of 5000 records?

example

```
Criteria crit = getCriteria(Product.clas)
crit.setMaxResult(5000)
crit.ResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY )
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to get rid of duplicated rows in Join (includes FetchType.eager), you need to use

   ```
   Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
   ```

   NOT

   ```
   Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY
   ```

   With Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY,  each row of results is an instance of the root entity.
2. In most of cases, I prefer to use two separated queries.

First query has only conditions with Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY and returns PK values.

Second query select results with pagination or max size limits by PKs from the first query's result.

```
// First Query
Criteria ct1 = createCriteria(Product.class)
    .add( Restrictions.eq("blah", val) )
    .setProjection(Projections.id());
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
List<Integer> pks = ct1.list();

// Second Query
Criteria ct2 = createCriteria(Product.class)
    .add( Restrictions.in("id", pks) )
    .setFirstResult(000)
    .setMaxResult(000)
return ct2.list();
```

The important problem is that we cannot apply pagination directly in first query. Because pagination options, setMaxResult or setFirstResult, is applied before Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY. So, we need to second query.

Comment: sorry I used Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY.  second query select results by PK values from the first query, with pagination or max size limits >> what do mean?

Comment: @seesee The first query's result is primary keys under your conditions and Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY. But you cannot apply pagination directly in there. Because pagination options, setMaxResult or setFirstResult, is applied before Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY.

Comment: So you need to use second query to do pagination options. I update my answer. Take a look please.

Comment: hmmm by the way what do you mean by pagination +1 for very good effort! I guess what you meant is, first you get 5000 products id and with those 5000 product ids, you use an in statement to get those products.. sadly IN only allow up to 1000 objects(oracle).

Comment: @seesee oops, in that case, why don't you try to this http://hartmann-schneevoigt.com/2012/07/06/how-to-get-distinct-results-in-hibernate-with-joins-and-row-based-paging/

Comment: that is interesting, I will take a look during the weekend.  There is so much to play with in in Java and Hibernate, I haven't time for computer games for a long time.

Comment: kkk  + I didn't try but the link that I posted seems use huge number of select query.